# Eliminating `flip` in Haskell lens

Tags: haskell, idioms, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm trying to get the hang of lenses. Is there a more idiomatic way to write the following? (placeholders preceded by underscores)

```hs
flip (set _lens) _a . fmap _f
```

To me, the use of `flip` seems to suggest non-idiomatic code. Is there a better combinator that avoids `flip` in this situation? Is there a more lens-like way of integrating the `fmap?`

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you expanded / completed the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might want to consider writing it pointed

```hs
\x -> _a & _lens .~ fmap _f x
```

which feels much more idiomatic to me.

If you really want it pointfree without `flip`, you can convert the above to pointfree:

```hs
(_a &) . set _lens . fmap _f
```

(Although technically, since `&` is equivalent to `flip ($)`, you're really just hiding the `flip`.)

Comment: The takeaway I take is, there's nothing serious I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think @DDub has covered the first half of your question.  As for a more "lens-like" way of integrating the `fmap`, this seems to be a special case of a more general problem.  If I have a setter:

```
> (1,"a") & _1 .~ True
(True,"a")
```

then I think there ought be a combinator that allows me to write:

```
> (1,"a") & _1 . applying not  .~ True
(False,"a")
```

This combinator doesn't *appear* to exist in `lens` (unless someone else can spot it), but you can define it as:

```
applying :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (c -> f a) -> (c -> f b)
applying f = (fmap f .)
```

or using the `Functor` instance for `(->) r` :

```
applying :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (c -> f a) -> (c -> f b)
applying = fmap . fmap
```

This leads to the amusing fact that the setter:

```
_lens . (fmap . fmap . fmap) _f
```

combines `_lens` with application of `fmap _f`, so the following produce equivalent results:

```
ex1 = (flip (set _1) ("a","b") . fmap not) $ Just True
ex2 = ("a","b") & _1 . applying (fmap not) .~ Just True
ex3 = ("a","b") & _1 . (fmap . fmap . fmap) not .~ Just True
-- all the above yield: (Just False,"b")
```

and are sure to amaze your friends.

Comment: I think my friends will say, that's not English and has waaay to much punctuation... :->